# fragment view is blank when I switch to from previous fragment view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When I populate a text view in a fragment, it shows up fine in the first fragment. But when I switch to a another fragment populated by another text file, it is blank.

Can some one help me understand why that it is?

Here is my code for first fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ResourcesFragment extends Fragment {


    public ResourcesFragment(){

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_resources, container, false);

        TextView text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtsource);
        text.setText("your text!");

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.resources);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        String entireFile = "";
        try {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place readLine() inside loop
                entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each line to entireFile
                //is.close();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //TextView text = null;
        //text.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to TextView
        //assert text != null;
        if (text != null) {
            text.setText(entireFile);

        }

        //return rootView;
        return rootView;

    }
}
```

I am doing the same thing in the second fragment but using a different source file:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TaweedFragment extends Fragment {

    public TaweedFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tawheed, container, false);

        TextView text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txttawheed);
        //text.setText("your text!");

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tawheed);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        String entireFile = "";
        try {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // <--------- place readLine() inside loop
                entireFile += (line + "\n"); // <---------- add each line to entireFile

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //TextView text = null;
        //text.setText(entireFile); // <------- assign entireFile to TextView
        //assert text != null;
        if (text != null) {
            text.setText(entireFile);
        }
        else {
            text.setText("");
            text.setText(entireFile);
        }

        //return rootView;
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong???
I tried closing the stream, but that didn't work.

ironmantis7x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my error was in the array resources that I set elsewhere in the main activity java file.
This is fixed.

IM7X